# sqlite3 with FTS4 table: Query returns wrong row

Tags: sql, sqlite, fts4

I have a weird issue with my FTS4 index in SQLite3, namely that a `MATCH` query for one term returns not the exact match but another, similar one, and vice versa.

Here is an example to illustrate it better:

```
SELECT name FROM test_idx WHERE name MATCH 'lehmbruck-museum';
-- "Lehmbruck-Archiv"
SELECT name FROM test_idx WHERE name MATCH 'lehmbruck-archiv';
-- "Lehmbruck-Museum"
```

It seems to have something to do with the dash, here is a similar case that exhibits the same behavior:

```
SELECT name FROM test_idx WHERE name MATCH 'some-thing';
-- "some-thang"
SELECT name FROM test_idx WHERE name MATCH 'some-thang';
-- "some-thing"
```

Here is how this test database is built, in case somebody wants to have a go at reproducing it:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE test_idx USING fts4(name);
INSERT INTO test_idx (name) VALUES
    ('some-thing'), ('some-thang'),
    ('Lehmbruck-Museum'), ('Lehmbruck-Archiv');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT name FROM test_idx WHERE name MATCH 'lehmbruck-museum';
```

What you pass to `MATCH` here is a full text query expression. The `-` character is a unary operator in that expression language that is a stand in for the `NOT` set operation, and is certainly giving you your unexpected results. Notably - the exact opposite of what you expect! Of course, it is finding exactly what the query is instructed to find - the string `lehmbruck` and NOT `museum` at the end!

You'll need to escape it to get the results you want - or perhaps employ the `LIKE` operator if you are looking at a single column in a table.

Some more information on this expression language can be found in section 3 of the FTS3 and FTS4 documentation on the SQLite doc site [here](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_3).

Comment: @jbaiter check out some of those examples on that page. Note that they employ the entire table in the MATCH and not a single column like name.